# Is there any callback function on redirection?

Tags: c++, c, curl

We need the application to be notified when redirection happens. Does curl offers an option to register a callback function when redirect response is received?

Comment: Do you mean libcurl? A command-line program rarely calls back into C or C++ code ...

Answer (score 1):

No, not at this time. However the matter has been discussed and it's likely that such functionality will be implemented in the future. Meanwhile there is [a patch for libcurl you might find useful](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2012-01/0184.html).

Comment: what needs to be set for client pointer which is passed as first argument to callback function? e.g. void *clientptr = ?

Comment: @ShwetaDevale: If you are referring to the patch -- sorry, I don't know.

Comment: I have used this patch and updated libcurl. Now I have written a program where I am using curl_seay_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_REDIRECTDATA,clientptr ). Here clientptr is declared as void *clientptr; But my query is how can I set this clientptr i.e to what value should I set for this pointer?